# MacBook Air Help Please

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Air and random advertisements and tabs have been popping up, I wanted to know if I take it to my nearest apple store can they figure out a way to help me fix this for free or at least at a low price?

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, it sounds like you have adware!

However, you can clean this up yourself very easily for free. There is a tool call AdwareMedic (which you can download from [this website](http://www.adwaremedic.com/index.php)); download it from the website, install it, and run it. It'll guide you through the steps, and when you're done, it will restart your computer. Once it turns back on, you should be free from all of those annoying ads. You can then uninstall AdwareMedic, if you would like.

I hope this helps you!